# Magento Enterprise order error

Tags: magento

Any ideas on why a magento order might have no title of prices in it? The SKU seems to be the only thing showing up that's related to the product.The customer paid zero for the order.  We seem to come across these type of orders once of twice a month.

We are using Magento Enterprise version 1.10.0.1

See error here:
[image]

Comment: Quick thing to check, though I don't know how it would happen in a live store anyway - are the products enabled? I've had similar things happen when manually creating orders in PHP scripts, when I forgot to ensure that the product was enabled. They'd show up free, and with a blank name. I don't remember if the SKU showed up in that case or not.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Yes the products are enabled.

Comment: check if currency selection or conversion is the cause.

Comment: Were this products simple products or childproducts of a bundle or configurable product?